# get_the_post_thumbnail Wordpress does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I have create a widget that show the post you decide, and display an img (that doesnt work), and the title, excerpt and a link work fine.

I can see the $post->ID is working fine; "add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );" is added too; The WP version is the last one.

```
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="' . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $post->post_title ). '">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full');
    echo '</a>';
```

When I run the widget I cant see the picture and this is the HTML:

```
<div class="latest_news-image"><a href="http://localhost/whatever/springs-is-in-the-headline/" title="Springs is in the headline"><img src="" alt="Home" class="thumbnail"></a></div>
```

This is the widget code:

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
die('-1');


add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
     register_widget( 'Latest_News_Widget' );
}); 

/**
 * Adds Latest News Widget.

 */
class Latest_News_Widget extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Register widget with WordPress.
 */
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'Latest_News_Widget', // Base ID
        __('Latest News Widget', 'text_domain'), // Name
        array('description' => __( 'Latest News Widget!', 'text_domain' ),) // Args
    );
}

/**
 * Front-end display of widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::widget()
 *
 * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
 * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    // get the excerpt of the required story
    if ( $instance['story_id'] == 0 ) {

        $gp_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'desc',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

        $posts = get_posts( $gp_args );

        if ( $posts ) {
            $post = $post[0];
        } else {
            $post = null;
        }

    } else {

        $post = get_post( $instance['story_id'] );  

    }

    if ( array_key_exists('before_widget', $args) ) echo $args['before_widget'];

    if ( $post ) {

      if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {        
    echo '<div class="latest_news-image">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" title="' . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $post->post_title ). '">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full');
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
  }

  echo '<div class="latest_news-text">';
        echo '<h3 class="story_widget_title">' . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $post->post_title ). '</h3>';
        echo '<p class="story_widget_excerpt">' . $post->post_excerpt . '</p>';
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" class="story_widget_readmore" title="Read the post, ' . $post->post_title . '">READ MORE</a>';
        echo '</div>';

    } else {

        echo __( 'No recent post found.', 'text_domain' );
    }

    if ( array_key_exists('after_widget', $args) ) echo $args['after_widget'];
}

/**
 * Back-end widget form.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::form()
 *
 * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
 */
public function form( $instance ) {

    if ( isset( $instance[ 'story_id' ] ) ) {
        $story_id = $instance[ 'story_id' ];
    }
    else {
        $story_id = 0;
    }
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'story_id' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Story:' ); ?></label> 

        <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'story_id' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'story_id' ); ?>">
            <option value="0">Most recent</option> 
    <?php 
    // get the exceprt of the most recent story
    $gp_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $gp_args );

        foreach( $posts as $post ) {

            $selected = ( $post->ID == $story_id ) ? 'selected' : ''; 

            if ( strlen($post->post_title) > 30 ) {
                $title = substr($post->post_title, 0, 27) . '...';
            } else {
                $title = $post->post_title;
            }

            echo '<option value="' . $post->ID . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $title . '</option>';

        }

    ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <?php 
}

/**
 * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::update()
 *
 * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
 * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
 *
 * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

    $instance = array();
    $instance['story_id'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['story_id'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['story_id'] ) : '';
    return $instance;
}

} // class Latest News Widget
```

Edit 1:

```
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID);
    echo $image_id;
    echo the_post_thumbnail($image_id, 'full');
```

I can see the number (79) but still is empty! :(

Edit 2:

To make it works I have to do it "manually"

```
  $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
    echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail_src[0].'" alt="' . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $post->post_title ). '" height="200" width="200">';
```

But I dont like this method.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: IMO your code should work. Try to unset the post image and set a new one. Maybe it is a strange bug...

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

```
`$thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "size" );`

if ( $thumbnail_src ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail_src[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $thumbnail_src[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $thumbnail_src[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Since you are trying to get the thumbnail within the loop like home page, category page or any other term page. you have to use - the_post_thumbnail();

If you want it in a specific page like single page, you should be using get_post_thumbnail_id($postId);

Also make sure you have added image otherwise it will return blank

Comment: @adrianVazquez i have updated the answer it will definitely work

Comment: I put this code and this is the html retrieve. <a href="http://localhost/whatever/springs-is-in-the-headline/" title="Springs is in the headline">Array</a>

Comment: @AdrianVazquez i have updated the answer please check and update your code accordingly , you need to pass array index in $thumbnail_src , becauuse it will return array now you need to divide that array in particular attribute

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the postdata for WordPress template tag functions to work. Sometimes its simply not enough to use: `global $post;`

Within the loop you need to use either: `setup_postdata( $post );` and after you are done: `wp_reset_postdata();` to make the postdata reset to its original post or page.

You do not have the WordPress loop in your widget code, you are only trying to use the global post object.

Example in your widget code, replace this with your `if( $post ){...}` part:

```
if ( $post ) {

  // Setup the $post so you can use template functions like: the_permalink(); etc...
  setup_postdata( $post );

  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {        
    echo '<div class="latest_news-image">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . apply_filters( 'widget_title', get_the_title() ). '">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'full' );
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
  }

  echo '<div class="latest_news-text">';
  echo '<h3 class="story_widget_title">' . apply_filters( 'widget_title', get_the_title() ). '</h3>';
  echo '<p class="story_widget_excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>';
  echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="story_widget_readmore" title="Read the post, ' . get_the_title() . '">READ MORE</a>';
  echo '</div>';


  // Reset the postdata so we avoid conflicts
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Relevant links to learn more about setup_postdata() and wp_reset_postdata() functions:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

If your having problems make sure:

- That the post actually HAS an post thumbnail.
- Check the image path, does it work to load directly in your browser?
- Test with other images as thumbnails
- Avoid multi byte chars in image filenames, this has resulted in broken images for me several times.